# Conflict with pushing commits using Sourcetree

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem with Sourcetree. I add two accounts, one from my company and second my private. There is no problem with using my business repo, I can push, pull, clone etc. but... I can clone my private repo, but I can't push changes.

```
Pushing to github.com:SKdaaaas/Fin.git
ERROR: Permission to SKdaaaas/Fin.git denied to KKwwdasd.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

SKdaaaas = My private GitHub username
KKwwdasd = My business GitHub username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that SourceTree is taking one default account for github.com.

Take a look in SourceTree in Options -> Authentication tab:

[image]

Your SourceTree setup seems to use your business account by default. If this is an option for you, you could add your business account as a collaborator of your private repo SKdaaaas/Fin.